# load product through ajax in opencart

Tags: php, ajax, opencart

I am having the following jquery ajax

```
fnc = {
    ajax : function (){
        $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=module/rows/filterView',
        type: 'get',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

This is my event registration

```
$(document).on('click','.loadfilter', function() {
    fnc.ajax();
})
```

And here is my controller

```
public function filterView() {
    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/collections.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/collections.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/module/collections.tpl';
        }

        $this->render();
}
```

In my collections.tpl I have a test content.

But when I click the link it is showing alert with empty. It doesn't contain any values.

Why I am getting empty alert. What is the mistake I am doing here. Can any one help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is really simple:

You are calling only `$this->render();` which only takes the template and renders it, while no output is done at all. To output the rendered template, You would need to call this:

```php
$this->response->setOutput($this->render());
```

If You are expecting a JSON to be outputted, then simply call

```php
$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($this->render()));
```

This could be figured out just by opening **any** OpenCart controller and checking out how the outputting and rendering are done...